# php - add cookie to curl's cookiejar

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'd like to be able to add cookies set from javascript into the cookie jar. Is there any PHP functions for this? or should i just open the cookie jar using fopen and hijack it?

Comment: Huh?! You really want to use browser-side JS to create a cookie, receive it with server-side PHP, and store in a cookie.jar file for use with PHP's curl library?

Comment: @Magicianeer depends what the motive is.

Comment: oh pardon me for being vague but apparently, im curling a site which sets cookies using a combination of javascript and php. and upon retrieving them, i could only get the php set ones. so i wanted to know how to add the javascript set cookies into the cookie jar.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested, in order to add cookies you have to add the cookie to the cookieFile mentioned in the cookie jar curl property.

```
file_put_contents($cookie, ".ebay.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   0   lucky9  ".$lucky9, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX,null);
```

Above is something I did to insert a cookie into my cookieFile.

The cookieFile contains a cookie in 7 tab delimited properties :

```
domain - The domain that created AND that can read the variable. 
flag - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if all machines within a given domain can access 
 the variable. This value is set automatically by the browser, depending on the value    you set 
 for domain. 
 path - The path within the domain that the variable is valid for. 
 secure - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if a secure connection with the domain is needed      to access the variable. 
 expiration - The UNIX time that the variable will expire on. UNIX time is defined as   the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. 
 name - The name of the variable. 
 value - The value of the variable.
```

Taken from [here.](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5)

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug:

You may use [Cookie Jar Writer](https://github.com/hindmost/cookiejarwriter).

> It is an utility PHP class for runtime editing cURL's cookie jar file.
>   In other words, it allows to add custom cookie variables to a cookie
>   jar file within sequence of cURL requests.

Answer (score 0):

Open cookie jar file in notepad and you will see format to save. It is simply plain text format with tab delemiter.

Answer (score 0):

php_curl prepends comments to its cookie file regarding the libraries that created the file and also including a link to the cookie spec. Check there for more information.

The spec is fairly simple.

I know of no purpose-built php functions/libraries to manipulate cookie files.  Rolling a custom one is fairly simple.